3.17 Brezis, $\ell^p$ convergence
I have been trying to try this exercise but either I have not understood it, or I have not been able to solve it. I would love to receive help on how to solve this exercise.
3.17

Let $\left(x^n\right)$ be a sequence in $\ell^p$ with $1 \leq p \leq \infty$. Assuming $x^n \rightharpoonup x$ in $\sigma\left(\ell^p, \ell^{p^{\prime}}\right)$ prove that:
(a) $\left(x^n\right)$ is bounded in $\ell^p$,
(b) $x_i^n \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} x_i$ for every $i$, where $x^n=\left(x_1^n, x_2^n, \ldots, x_i^n, \ldots\right)$ and $x=$ $\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_i, \ldots\right)$
Conversely, suppose $\left(x^n\right)$ is a sequence in $\ell^p$ with $1<p \leq \infty$. Assume that (a) and (b) hold (for some limit denoted by $x_i$ ). Prove that $x \in \ell^p$ and that $x^n \rightharpoonup x$ in $\sigma\left(\ell^p, \ell^{p^{\prime}}\right)$.

I don't know if part a) should come out directly because $x^n \in \ell^p$ and consequently is bounded in the norm? For b), I really have no idea how I could solve it, only I found this link about a previous question:
Pointwise convergence and boundedness imply weak convergence in $\ell^\infty$
[EDIT:] I think b) it is possible prove with using that $x_i^n = \langle e_i, x^n \rangle \to \langle e_i, x \rangle = x_i$.  Then $x_i^n \to x_i$ weak.
[EDIT 2:] I think that this way of solving is true. To solve 2, we must show that the projections are dense on $E'$?

"$x^{n}\in\ell^{p}$ and consequently is bounded in norm". You are misunderstanding the point. If it was that simple then why at all give it as an exercise? You have to show that $\sup_{n}||(x^{n})||_{\ell^{p}}<\infty$. That can be done by applying the Uniform Boundedness Principle. This is true for general Banach spaces that weakly convergent sequences are bounded in norm.

Also note that the conclusion fails when $p=1$. I have given counter examples in my answer.

First, for any Banach Space $X$ and a weakly convergent sequence $x_{n}$, define $T_{n}\in X^{**}$ by $T_{n}(f)=f(x_{n})$.
Then see that $T_{n}$'s are linear and continuous. Now, for each $f$, $\sup_{n}|T_{n}(f)|<C_{f}$ for some $C_{f}$ (depending on $f$) as $f(x_{n})$ is convergent. Thus the Uniform Boundedness Principle tells you that $\sup_{n}||T_{n}||<\infty$. But $||T_{n}||=\sup_{||f||\leq 1}|f(x_{n})|$
Thus $\sup_{n}\sup_{||f||\leq 1}|f(x_{n})|<\infty$ . You can apply the Hahn-Banach Theorem to show that $\sup_{||f||\leq 1}|f(x)|=||x||$ for each $x\in X$.
i.e. you always have $|f(x)|\leq ||x||$ if $||f||=1$. But you can define $g:(\Bbb{K}x)\to\Bbb{K}$ by $g(tx)=t||x||$. Then $||g||\leq 1$ and $g$ is linear and thus, by Hahn-Banach Theorem, there exists $G:X\to\Bbb{K}$ such that $||G||\leq 1$ and $G|_{(\Bbb{K}x)}=g$ . Thus you have that $G(x)=||x||$ and $\sup_{||f||\leq 1}|f(x)|=||x||$.
This shows you that $\sup_{n}\sup_{||f||\leq 1}|f(x_{n})|=\sup_{n}||x_{n}||<\infty$ .
Thus you have $(a)$. For $(b)$ you only need to note that $x^{n}_{i}=\langle e_{i},x^{n}\rangle\to \langle e_{i},x\rangle=x_{i}$ because $e_{i}\in (\ell^{p})^{*}$.

Converse
Note that if $\mu$ denotes the counting measure on $\Bbb{N}$, then $\displaystyle\int_{\Bbb{N}} |x|^{p}\,d\mu=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|x_{j}|^{p}$ for any $x\in\ell^{p},p<\infty$
Let $(a)$ and $(b)$ hold. And let $p=\infty$ for the while. We'll show that for $y\in\ell^{1}$, you have $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}y_{j}x^{n}_{j}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}y_{j}x_{j}$ which is what is asked.
Note : This is not the same as saying that for all $f\in(\ell^{\infty})^{*}$, you have that $\langle f,x^{n}\rangle\to \langle f,x\rangle$ . That is false. But, for the particular topology $\sigma(\ell^{\infty},\ell^{1})$ ( weak$^*$ topology in the dual of $\ell^{1}$), you do have what is asked in the question. The point being that the weak$^{*}$ topology on $\ell^{\infty}$ is not the same as
the weak topology on $\ell^{\infty}$.
Note that you have $\sup_{n}\sup_{j}|x_{j}^{n}|<\infty$ and thus $|x_{j}^{n}|\leq C$ for all $j$ and $n$ for some constant $C$.
So, you have that $|y_{j}x^{n}_{j}|\leq C|y_{j}|$ and $\displaystyle\int_{\Bbb{N}}|y|\,d\mu=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|y_{j}|<\infty$ .
Thus, as $y_{j}x^{n}_{j}\to y_{j}x_{j}$, By the Dominated Convergence Theorem, you have that
$$\int_{\Bbb{N}}yx^{n}\,d\mu=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}y_{j}x^{n}_{j}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}y_{j}x_{j}=\int_{\Bbb{N}}yx\,d\mu$$
Thus $x^{n}\xrightarrow{w^{*}}x$ for $p=\infty$

For $p=1$, unfortunately, the conclusion is false and it seems to be a mistake in the book.
For a simple counter example, let $x^{n}$ be $e_{n}$. Then $x^{n}_{i}$ converges to $0$ for each $i$ and $||x^{n}||=1$ for each $n$. But for the functional $1\in\ell^{\infty}$, you have $\langle 1,x^{n}\rangle=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}x^{n}_{j}=1$ which is not $\langle 1,0\rangle=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} 0\cdot 1=0$
Infact, strong convergence is the same as weak convergence in $\ell^{1}$ due to a Theorem of Schur so you don't have strong or weak convergence in this case.

Now let $1<p<\infty$. Now $\ell^{p}$ is Reflexive.
First note that by Fatou's Lemma and assumption (a) $$\int_{\Bbb{N}}|x|^{p}\,d\mu=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|x_{j}|^{p}\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\inf\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}|x^{n}_{j}|^{p}<\infty$$ as $\sup_{n}||x^{n}||_{\ell^{p}}<\infty$. Thus $x\in\ell^{p}$
Now use Theorem $3.18$ in Brezis which states that every bounded sequence in a reflexive Banach space has a weakly convergent subsequence.
So, let $x^{n_{k}}$ be an arbitrary subsequence of $x^{n}$. Then, you have that $\sup_{k}||x^{n_{k}}||_{\ell^{p}}$ is bounded and thus, there exists a further subsequence $x^{n_{k_{l}}}$ which converges weakly to some $z$ (say).
And hence $\langle e_{i},x^{n_{k_{l}}}\rangle\to z_{i}$. But, you already have that $$\langle e_{i},x^{n_{k_{l}}}\rangle=x^{n_{k_{l}}}_{i}\to x_{i}$$
Thus $x_{i}=z_{i}$ for all $i$  and hence $x=z$.
So, what we have now shown is that given any subsequence of $x^{n}$, there exists a further subsequence which converges weakly to $x$. I claim that this is sufficient to show that $x^{n}\rightharpoonup x$. This would completes the exercise. (This is a very useful criteria for checking weak convergence). Try to prove it. If you can't then see below

 So let $X$ be any Normed Space and $f\in X^{*}$ and let $x_{n}$ be a
 sequence such that given any subsequence, there exists a further
 subsequence which converges weakly to $x$.

 Then you have that the real/complex sequence $f(x_{n})$ satisfies the
 property that any given subequence of it has a further subequence
 which converges to $f(x)$. This is a critria for sequences in a
 metric space to converge.


 Thus $f(x_{n})\to f(x)$ and this holds for all $f$ and hence
 $x_{n}\rightharpoonup x$


Alternatively, As @geetha290krm suggests,
Let $y\in\ell^{p'}$.
Now, by Holder's Inequality, and using that $\sup_{n}||x^{n}||_{\ell^{p}}<\infty$ $$\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}|y_{k}(x^{n}_{k}-x_{k})|\leq (\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}|y_{k}|^{p'})^{1/p'}(\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}|x^{n}_{k}-x_{k}|^{p})^{1/p}\leq C(\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}|y_{k}|^{p'})^{1/p'}$$
where $C$ is a constant.
Thus, given $\epsilon>0$, you can find an $M$(depending on $\epsilon$) such that $m\geq M$ implies $\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}|y_{k}(x^{n}_{k}-x_{k})|<\epsilon$. This is because $\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}|y_{k}|^{p'}\to 0$ as $m\to\infty$.
Now $\displaystyle\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}y_{k}(x_{k}^{n}-x_{k})\bigg|=\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^{M}y_{k}(x_{k}^{n}-x_{k})+\sum_{k=M}^{\infty}y_{k}(x_{k}^{n}-x_{k})\bigg|$
Now choose $N$ (depending on $\epsilon$ and $M$ and hence only on $\epsilon$) such that $n\geq N$ implies $\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^{M}y_{k}(x_{k}^{n}-x_{k})\bigg|<\epsilon$ (this can be done due to coordinate wise convergence).
Thus, for all $n\geq N$, you have that
$$\bigg|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}y_{k}(x_{k}^{n}-x_{k})\bigg|<2\epsilon$$ which shows that $\langle y,x^{n}\rangle\to \langle y,x\rangle$

Simpler proof: Fix $y \in \ell^{p'}$. $\sum_N^{\infty} |y_i(x^{n}_i-x_i)|<\epsilon$ for $N$ large enough, by Hölder's inequality. Rest is clear.

My argument is for $1<p<\infty$.
